# Unable to change Angular Select after ng-show

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've ran into this before with `ng-src` but I don't know how to handle it with an `<select>`. Pretty simple deal but after the select dropdown shows up the value can't be changed. I've tried `$apply()` and `$compile()` without any luck.

I think the issue is that Angular doesn't know to compile that element. Any ideas? Here's the code...

```
<blockquote class="header10">
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="panel.style" value="Rods and Rings">Rod and Rings
  </label>
  <select ng-hide="!(panel.style == 'Rods and Rings')" ng-model="panel.style.rodsAndRings">
    <option value="">--Choose Header--</option>
    <option>Butterfly Pleats (2 inch)</option>
    <option>Cuff Tops</option>
    <option>Fan Pleats</option>
    <option>Flat</option>
    <option>Goblet Pleats</option>
    <option>Inverted Box Pleats</option>
    <option>Pencil Pleats</option>
    <option>Pinch Pleats (4 inch)</option>
    <option>Tab Tops</option>
    <option>Tie Tops</option>
    <option>Other</option>
  </select>
  <div ng-hide="!(panel.style.rodsAndRings == 'Other')">
    <p>Other <input type="text"></p>
  </div>
</blockquote>
```

The behavior is that after the `select` element is shown, I can still see the values and selecting any of them always reverts to the default `--Choose Header--` because it is never taken.

Test case on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/dTYcCi6aT3H5Gm7TEvyc?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `panel.style.rodsAndRings` isn't a valid ng-model.
You defined `panel.style` to be a string primitive, so attaching a property to it won't work.  Try changing your model to be something different, like `panel.selected`

Also I would recommend using angulars ng-options instead of hard coding in your options

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I do need it to be a nested object. Maybe if I define it in the controller that will work. Thoughts?

Comment: Actually, I guess I don't have to use the nested property and can just explicitly name those properties on the root object. My goal was to have proper namespacing because this is quite the form. Anyway, thanks for your help and it does answer the question.

Comment: As this is the correct answer, I will delete my wrong answer.

Comment: You can do it nested, but you would need to define panel.style as an object, ie panel.style = {}.  Then make a rodsAndRings property on it and it will work just fine